# How to redirect with 2 or more variables using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, variables, redirect

I'm trying to redirect from 2 differents URL's just taking 2 or more params. I done this a couple of times but my memory is being really bad and i don't remember how to do it (age thing i think).

example:

```
from http://www.abc.net/forum/index.php/board,(\d+).0.html
to http://www.abc.com/forum?view=category&catid=%1

from http://www.abc.net/forum/index.php/board,(\d+).(\d+).html
to http://www.abc.com/forum?view=category&catid=%1&other=%2
```

And probably more but i will solve it with some help:

My bad example:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^board,(\d+).0.html$
RewriteRule ^/forum/index.php$ http://www.abc.com/forum?view=category&catid=%1 [L,R]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: In the incoming URL, this `d,(\d+).0.html`, for example, is literal so can't match `,(\d+).0.html$` in your regex. Should be something like `\w,[^\.].\d\.[^/]+/?` Just an idea so you can adjust the regex if necessary. Or, you could escape all metacharacters in the regex to make them literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `board,(\d+).0.html` stuff isn't in the query string. You want to match those just like you would any part of the URI:

```
RewriteRule ^/?forum/index\.php/board,([0-9]+)\.0\.html$ /forum?view=category&catid=$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^/?forum/index\.php/board,([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.html$ /forum?view=category&catid=$1&other=$2 [L,R]
```